# params looking for id being fired on another route when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to mongoose so I apologise for incorrect uses of terminology.

I have a routes file as detailed below

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const controller = require('./clubController');
const authGuard = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });
const verifyUser = require('./clubController').verifyUser;
const isSiteAdmin = require('./clubController').isSiteAdmin;

router.param('id', controller.params);

router.route('/')
    .post(authGuard, controller.newClub)
    .get(controller.allPublicClubs);

router.route('/:id')
    .put(authGuard, verifyUser(), controller.editClub)
    .get(controller.getClub);

router.route('/private')
    .get(controller.allPrivateClubs);

module.exports = router;
```

### controller.params

```
exports.params = function(req, res, next, id) {
    Club.findById(id)
        .populate('creator teams', '-password -email -role')
        .exec()
        .then(function(club) {
            if (!club) {
                return res.status(404).send({ msg: 'No Club exists with that ID' });
            } else {
                req.club = club;
                next();
            }
        }, function(err) {
            // error handling
            next(err);
        });
};
```

`controller.params` is being fired when I make a get request to `/private`. To my understanding, the params middleware I have setup should only be fired when a called route is using an `id` parameter.

The value for the `id` argument in `controller.params` is set as `private` which is the route.

The error I receive is detailed below
`CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "private" at path "_id" for model "club"`

This was working fine yesterday, no idea what changed that it now does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by moving

```
router.route('/:id')
    .put(authGuard, verifyUser(), controller.editClub)
    .get(controller.getClub);
```

To the bottom of all the routes. Was strange as I had the same order before and it worked fine

Comment: If this solved your question, please mark it correct.

Comment: @Soviut Need to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer